# Multiple submit buttons in form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a shopping cart and would like the option to remove an item from the cart. I do not want to use javascript. The items in the cart are looped through in php by grabbing the session variable, and displayed in a table with the option to remove the item. As of right now I have multiple input submits for the "remvove item" link, and inside my for loop I have these input tags which are generated with the ID of the item.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>
<input type="submit" name="remove" value="removeitem" class="otherbtns" />
```

My problem is in my script that handles the post variables has no way of knowing which "removeitem" link was clicked, hence removing the first one. I'm just kinda looking for the best way to handle soemthing like this without JS.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want without Javascript, an alternative would be to have checkboxes, and a remove items button.

Answer (score 3):

Could you possibly make multiple forms each with a different value for the action attribute?

Comment: Then you can't have an overall form for the cart. Forms cannot be within forms.

Comment: If you configure the session variables properly you shouldn't need an overall form.

Comment: Another alternative is to make the remove from cart buttons links to say "http://www.example.com/cart?removeID=123". Then, handle the $_GET variable accordingly.

Comment: Fair point, however what is in the session isn't necessarily what is on the page. Could have multiple pages open, added a new item, didn't refresh the page they're on. I think if you hit the actual submit button you should be submitting what you are looking at, not what might be in the session.

Comment: Using links is an option, but is against the specification of what GET should be used for. "The GET method means retrieve ... information...". :)

Comment: Yeah, guess you're right. He could warn the user that the cart has changed since the time he/she opened the page.

Comment: Yea, its a hard situation to do nicely without javascript.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good thing he's not depending on JavaScript, though. It can lead to some angry customers who have JavaScript disabled. Hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple forms. You can have as many forms as you want in your script, one submit per form. Do not take the path of using js to submit your form -> kittens will die if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

read your `$id[$i]` from database and save amount of records to `$count`
then check if you need to delete something:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
  if (isset($_POST[$id[$i]])) { 
    remove your $id[$i] from database
  }
}
```

then read your `$id[$i]` from database again and save amount of records to `$count`

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $count; $i++) {
  echo '<input type="submit" name="'.$id[$i]'." value="removeitem">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind exposing the `id` value to the user, a quick-n-dirty way to fix it would be changing the `value` attribute of each submit button:

```
<input type="submit" ... value="removeitem <?php echo $uniqueid ?>" />
```

Then, when the form is sent to the server, you can parse and check the value with PHP. Depending on how complicated your IDs are, you could do something as simple as this:

```
$value = $_POST['remove'];
$value = explode(' ', $value);
$value = $value[1];
```

...And that would theoretically give you the ID you need.

Comment: thanks thats gonna be the way i do it, i dont see any risk with user knowing my item id

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with a simple link to the same page, but in the $_GET gather the information and have it run through a script:

```
<a href="cart.php?remove=yes&item_to_remove=<?php echo item_id; ?>">Remove</a>
```

Then in the php script

```
if ( (isset($_GET['remove']))and($_GET['remove'] == 'yes') ){
   //then remove the item from the session var by removing the $_GET['item_to_remove']
}
```

Comment: As I commented when Tyler suggested this, its against the HTTP specification to use GET to do something like this.

Comment: Have a look at why not to use GET. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56522/is-there-ever-a-situation-where-its-ok-to-initiate-a-delete-on-a-get/56526#56526

Comment: Jacob, I understand the concern you have here, but the link you provided show how a get can potential delete records you don't want from a database.  This situation is different since they are using sessions which are storing items from a shopping cart.  It is unlikely that Google (from the answer to the question per your link) is not going to put things into a shopping cart.  Further, even if they did the removal of the items from the session will not effect the database so in this case I don't see this being a problem.